# Splitting a string using a semi colon in XML 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to re work a XSLT that I have not written to spepate job roles on different rows with their own tags.

The code currently shows the whole string complete with semi colons

```
<xsl:value-of select="Properties/Property[Name='accountability']/Value" />
```

currently produces

```
<Consulted>viewpoint manager;design management lead;bim specialist</Consulted>
```

I have tried editing the code by adding a recursive test that I have taken from another post, but it fails to produce an output. I have tried using a straight semi colon, ASCII and hex charachters but with no success

Here is the XSLT-1.0 code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <RolesData>
            <Activities>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="XmlCatalogue/File/Map/MapPages/MapPage/Activities/Activity">
                    <xsl:sort select="Level" order="ascending" />
                    <xsl:sort select="Name" order="ascending" />

                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </Activities>
        </RolesData>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="sep" select="'&#59;'"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $sep)">
                <!-- recursive call -->
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $sep)" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Activity">
        <Activity>
            <Consulted>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="Properties/PropertyName='consulted']/Value"/>
                </xsl:call-template>

            </Consulted>
        </Activity>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is your input XML?

Comment: And also interesting: what is your desired output?

Comment: Your tokenizing template does not output anything, because it does not write anything to the output. Surely in the original post it created either a text node or an element, before calling itself again.